# particular solution guess to $2e^x + e^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why is the guess to the particular solution of $y''-2y'+y = 2e^x + e^{-x}$ equal to $Ax^2*e^x+Be^{-x}$ and not $Ae^x+Be^{-x}$?

Comment: It is due to the fact that
$$(Ae^x)''-2(Ae^x)'+(Ae^x)=0$$
Also
$$(Axe^x)''-2(Axe^x)'+(Axe^x)=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because $1$ is a double root of the characteristic equation $\lambda^2-2\lambda +1=0$. So $e^{ x}$ and $xe^{x}$ are both solutions of the homogeneous equation, and we have to go to $x^\color{red}{2} e^x$ (next power of $x$) when looking for a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $y''-2y'+y = 2e^x + e^{-x}\implies (D^2-2D+1)y=2e^x + e^{-x}$, where $D \equiv \frac{d}{dx}$

The trial solution is $m^2-2m+1=0\implies (m-1)^2=0\implies m=1, 1$

Since the trial solution gives repeated roots, so

Complementary function (C.F.) $$y=(Ax+B)e^x$$ where $A, B$ are integrating constants.

Now the Particular Integral (P.I.)$\quad=\frac{1}{D^2-2D+1}(2e^x + e^{-x})$

$=\frac{1}{(1-D)^2}(2e^x + e^{-x})$

$= 2 \frac{x^2}{2}e^{x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{4}$

$=x^2 e^{x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{4}$

So the general solution of the given differential equation is $$y(x)=(Ax+B)e^x+x^2 e^{x}+\frac{e^{-x}}{4}$$

---

> Consider a differential equation of the form $f(D)y=X$
>
> If $X=e^{ax}$, then
>
> $1.$ P.I.$\quad = \frac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}=\frac{e^{ax}}{f(a)}$, if $f(a)\neq 0$
>
> $2.$ P.I.$\quad =\frac{1}{(D-a)^n}e^{ax}=\frac{x^n}{n!}e^{ax}$

Comment: how did you deduce that $m=\pm 1$ from $(m-1)^2=0$ in the second line???

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo.